# Solve $x^2+5x+6 \equiv 0 \pmod{\!11\cdot 17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Solve $x^2+5x+6 \equiv 187 \mod 187$

### Solution

$$x^2+5x+6 \equiv 187 \mod 187$$
$$ (x+\frac{5}{2})^2 \equiv \frac{1}{4}$$
$$ 4(x+\frac{5}{2})^2 \equiv 1$$
$$ y:= x+\frac{5}{2} $$

$$ 4y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 11 \wedge 4y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 17  $$
$$ ( 2y \equiv 1 \mod 11 \vee 2y \equiv 10 \mod 11 ) \wedge ( 2y \equiv 1 \mod 17  \vee 2y \equiv 13 \mod 17)  $$
$$ ( y \equiv 6 \mod 11 \vee y \equiv 5 \mod 11 ) \wedge ( y \equiv 9 \mod 17  \vee y \equiv 15 \mod 17)  $$
Combining that from CRT I got:
$$ y \in \left\{49, 60,83,94 \right\} $$
and for example:
$$ x+\frac{5}{2}  \equiv 94 \mod 187$$
$$ 2x  \equiv 183 \mod 187$$
some calculus and get...
$$x \equiv 185 $$
And the same thing for each other case.

### Question

Is there any faster (or smarter) way to solve equations like that?

Comment: Correction:  If $4y^2\equiv1\mod 17$ then $2y\equiv1$ or $1\color{red}6\mod 17$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: applying CRT as in the Remark below yields

$$(x\!+\!2)(x\!+\!3)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!11\cdot 17}\iff \begin{align} x\equiv -2,-3\!\!\!\pmod{\!11}\\ x\equiv -2,-3\!\!\!\pmod{\!17}\end{align}\qquad\qquad $$

which combine to $4$ solutions $\,x\equiv (\color{#90f}{{ -2,-2}}),\,(\color{#f80}{-3,-3}),\,\color{#c00}{(-2,-3)},\,\color{#0af}{(-3,-2)}$ mod $(11,17)$.  By [CCRT,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) $\bmod 187,\ $  first $\,2\,$ yield $\,x\equiv \color{#90f}{ -2},\,$ and $\,\color{#f80}{-3};\ $  3rd  $\ \color{#c00}{(-2,-3)}\,$ yields, by [CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242)

$\!\overbrace{\bmod\ \color{#0a0}{11}\!:\ \   \color{#c00}{{-}2} \equiv\, x \equiv \color{#c00}{-3}+17\,\color{#0a0}k}^{x\,\equiv\,\color{#c00}{(-2,-3)}\iff \begin{align}&x\ \equiv \color{#c00}{-2}\pmod{\!11}\\ &x\ \equiv \color{#c00}{-3}\pmod{\!17}\end{align}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\, \equiv-3+6k$ $ \iff 6k\equiv1\equiv12 \iff \color{#0a0}{k \equiv 2}$

therefore we infer $\ x = -3+17(\color{#0a0}{2+11}n) = \color{#c00}{31}+187n,\ $ so $\ \color{#c00}{(-2,-3)\,\mapsto\, 31}$

For 4th:   $\ \color{#0af}{(-3,-2)} + \color{#c00}{\underbrace{(-2,-3)}_{\large31}}\equiv \underbrace{(-5,-5)}_{\large -5}$ $\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0af}{(-3,-2)}\,\mapsto\, -5-\color{#c00}{31}\equiv -36\ $

**Remark** $ $ Note that $\,x\!+\!3\,,x\!+\!2\,$ are coprime (having difference $=1),\,$ so a prime power $\,p^n$ divides their product iff it divides exactly one of them, so the above method still works if we replace $11$ and $17$ by powers of distinct primes.

Generally, if $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ mod $\,m\,$ and mod $\,n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\bmod m\,$ and a root $\,s_j\bmod n\,$ corresponds to a unique root $\,t_{ij}\bmod mn,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn}&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m}\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \\ 
&\,\,\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_k\pmod{\! m}\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_\ell\pmod{\! n}\end{array}\\ 
&\,\,\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_i\pmod{\! m}\\x\equiv s_j\pmod {\! n}\end{array} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}^{\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}}\\
&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \left\{ x\equiv t_{i j}\!\!\pmod{\!mn} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

For more complex examples it is usually easier to solve the CRT system first for generic (symbolic) roots, then plug in the specific root values for all combinations, e.g.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864763/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2052030/242)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3627065/242) for an example where the polynomial differs for each modulus.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^2+5x+6=(x+2)(x+3)$,\begin{align}x^2+5x+6\equiv187\pmod{187}&\iff(x+2)(x+3)\equiv0\pmod{187}\\&\iff(11\mid x+2\vee11\mid x+3)\wedge(17\mid x+2\vee17\mid x+3).\end{align}

Comment: I would just add that the two "parallel" solutions $x\equiv -2$ and $x\equiv -3$ immediately work $\bmod 187$. The two mixed solutions eg $x+2\equiv 0 \bmod 11, x+3\equiv 0 \bmod 17$ require a little more work to pin down.

Comment: @Mark Actually we only need to solve one of the mixed cases since their sum is $\equiv -5\pmod{187},\,$ which yields the other case - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque noted - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+5x+6\equiv187\equiv0 \pmod {187=11\times17}$$

$$(x+2)(x+3)\equiv 0 \pmod {11  , 17}$$

$$x\equiv-2 \text { or } -3 \pmod {11, 17}$$

Now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Solve $x^2+5x+6 \equiv (x+2)(x+3) \pmod {187}$.

Besides the two 'in your face' solutions, $x \equiv -2 \pmod{187}$ and $x \equiv -3 \pmod{187}$, we can buttress the argument given by José Carlos Santos to find all four solutions.

We want to find integers $x, k, j$ satifying

$\;\text{L1:}\quad x + 2 = 11k$
$\;\text{L2:}\quad x + 3 = 17j$

Subtracting $\text{L1}$ from $\text{L2}$ we write

$\tag 1 1  = 17j - 11k$

Bézout's identity gives us

$\quad 1 = 17(2) - 11(3)$

So $k = 3$ and, plugging into $\text{L1}$,  $x \equiv 31 \pmod{187}$ is a solution.

For the last solution,

$\;\text{L1:}\quad x + 2 = 17j$
$\;\text{L2:}\quad x + 3 = 11k$

Subtracting $\text{L1}$ from $\text{L2}$ we write

$\tag 2 1  = -17j + 11k$

Bézout's identity gives us

$\quad 1 = 17(2) - 11(3)$

So $k = -3$ and, plugging into $\text{L2}$,  $x = -36 \equiv 151 \pmod{187}$  is a solution.

It can also be argued that there are exactly four solutions.