# $(2x + 1)(3x + 1) \equiv 0\pmod{\!n}$ has a root for all $n ≥ 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have a feeling that induction might be necessary since the question includes "for every integer $n ≥ 2$".

So with this in mind, the base case would be $n=2$. If $(2x+1)(3x+1)\equiv0\pmod 2$, then $x=1$ is a solution because $12\equiv 0\pmod 2$ is a true statement.

For the inductive step, we assume that
$$(2x+1)(3x+1)\equiv0\pmod{k}$$
and we need to show that $$(2x+1)(3x+1)\equiv 0\pmod{ (k+1)}.$$
I'm unsure what to do from here.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: We can use strong induction, base case is what you showed. For inductive step, we have $k+1=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}...$ where the $p_i's$ are distinct primes. Apply induction on each of the $p_i^{r_i}$ to get $(2x+1)(3x+1)≡0(mod  p_1^{r_1})$, $(2x+1)(3x+1)≡0(mod p_2^{r_2})$ and so on. Since each of the $p_i^{r_i}$ are coprime, we can apply Chinese remainder theorem to conclude that $(2x+1)(3x+1)≡0(mod k+1)$ has a solution!

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $x=\dfrac{n-1}2$ is a solution; if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ then $n-1$ or $2n-1$ is a multiple of $3$ so $\dfrac{n-1}3$ or $\dfrac{2n-1}3$ is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without induction on $n$.   Let $n=2^am$ with $m$ odd.  Then $2^a$ is not a multiple of $3,$

so $2^a-1$ or $2^{a+1}-1$ is a multiple of $3, $ and $x=\dfrac{2^a-1}3$ or $x=\dfrac{2^{a+1}-1}3 $ is a solution$\mod 2^a$.

Also, $x=\dfrac{m-1}2$ is a solution $\mod m$.

Therefore, by the Chinese remainder theorem, there is a solution $\mod n$.

Comment: Thanks to [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown) for suggesting the CRT

Comment: This works precisely because $2$ and $3$ are coprime - see my answer.

Comment: Note that you don't need to *explictly* solve $\, \color{#0a0}3x\!+\!1\equiv 0\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{2^a}}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}2x\!+\!1\equiv 0\pmod{\!\color{#c00}m}.\,$ Here we only need to know that solutions *exist*, which follows from the well-known [solvability criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) for linear congruences, since $\,\color{#0a0}{(3,2^a)}=1=\color{#c00}{(2,m)}.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem** $\ f(x)= (ax\!+\!1)(bx\!+\!1)\ $ has a root $\!\bmod n\,$ for all $\,n\!>\!1\!\iff\! (a,b) = 1$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ if $\,1 < c\mid a,b\,$ then $\!\bmod c\!: f(x)\equiv 1\not\equiv 0.\,$ $(\Leftarrow)\,$ Factor $\,n = a'b'$ where $\,b'\,$ collects all prime factors of $\,n\,$ that divide $\,a,\,$ so $\,1 \!=\! (a,a'),\,$ and $\,1 \!=\! (b,b') = (a',b'),\,$ by $\,(a,b)\!=\!1,\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{ax\!+\!1}\,$ has root $\,\color{#0a0}{x\equiv -a^{-1}\!\pmod{\!a'}}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{bx\!+\!1}\,$ has root $\,\color{#c00}{x\equiv -b^{-1}\!\pmod{\!b'}}.\,$ Therefore $\,f(x)\!=\!(\color{#0a0}{ax\!+\!1})(\color{#c00}{bx\!+\!1})\,$ has a root $\!\color{#0a0}{\bmod a'}\,$ & $\!\color{#c00}{\bmod b'},\:\!$ which [CRT lifts to a root](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242) $\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{a'}\color{#c00}{b'}\!=\!n$.

Answer (score 0):

Without CRT but EL.

Let $n=2^km$ where $m$ is odd.

Since $\gcd(2,m)=1$ $\exists t_1,t_2\in\Bbb Z$ such that $2t_1+1=t_2m$.

Since $\gcd(3,2^k)=1$ $\exists s_1,s_2\in\Bbb Z$ such that $3s_1+1=s_22^k$.

Since $\gcd(m,2^k)=1$ $\exists u,v\in\Bbb Z$ such that $um+v2^k=1$.

Let $x=t_1+(s_1-t_1)um.$

Then $(2x+1)(3x+1)\equiv 0\pmod n.$

Comment: @BillDubuque But I didn't use CRT directly. Right?

Comment: @BillDubuque Omg. You wrote an his tory on that subject.

Comment: **You do apply CRT** (without saying its name). Your first three equations are equivalent to $\,\color{#0a0}{t_1\equiv -1/2}\pmod{\!m},\,$ $\color{#0a0}{s_1\equiv -1/3}\pmod{\!2^k},\,$ $\color{#c00}{u\equiv m^{-1}}\!\pmod{\!2^k}.\,$ Then you claim

$$\begin{align}&x\equiv \color{#0a0}{t_1}\!\!\!\pmod{m}\\&x\equiv \color{#0a0}{s_1}\!\!\!\pmod{2^k}\end{align}\Longleftarrow\ x\equiv t_1 + (s_1-t_1)\,m(\underbrace{\color{#c00}{m^{-1}}\bmod  2^k}_{\textstyle \color{#c00}u^{\phantom{\tiny i}}})\qquad$$
which is *exactly* the [(Easy) CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242).$\ \ $

Comment: Thus what you wrote is *exactly* the same method I used (but I didn't apply any specific CRT *formula* since here we need only the *existence* of a root). So it is a duplicate of the method in my answer. It's best not to duplicate answers unless there is a very good reason to do so. $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque For this particular question it is obviously "another way" solution.

Comment: No, it is *exactly* the same way, as I explained above. But doing it as above obfuscates the use of CRT, so obscures the underlying key idea.

Comment: I started from EDL which is more basic. I am not trying to degrade CRT or other answers