# number theory Congruence question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on a question of Congruence . I would like u to give me a hint or a direction for what I have reached so far.
I have got that: $$ (x-p_1)\cdot(x-p_2)\equiv\ 0\pmod{p_1p_2} $$
When: $p_1, p_2$ are prime.

Comment: Are you asking if this is true, or is this part of a bigger question that you have not put here, and that you are asking about that bigger question?

Comment: We don't know where you are trying to go; we don't know what you are trying to say. It is impossible to give you a hint or direction. This question, right now, is not even a question.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this equation? Expand $x^2-(p_1+p_2)x+p_1p_2\equiv0\mod{p_1p_2}$ and show it is the same as $(x-(p_1+p_2))x\equiv0\mod{p_1p_2}$. Perhaps you can see how to proceed.

Comment: I am so sorry guys... I had to solve this equation, i.e. to find all potential results of x, when p1 and p2 are prime. 
I still get stuck on this.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242) for a general method using CRT.

Comment: so I get: $$x\equiv\ p_1,p_2\ (mod\ p_1), and \  x\equiv\ p_1,p_2\ (mod\ p_2)? $$

Comment: I forgot to tag u. @Bill Dubuque

Comment: Yes, now you need to lift those to up to $4$ roots  mod $\,p_1 p_2\,$ using CRT, as in the link. You'll get the "constant" roots $,p_1,p_2,\,$ and two other "mixed" roots that yield $\,x\equiv 0,\,p_1+p_2\ \ $