# A question about comaximal ideals in a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Consider the following question from my ring theory assignment:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $\mathfrak a_1,...,\mathfrak a_m $ be pairwise comaximal ideals in $A$ and $\mathfrak a=\mathfrak a_1\cdots\mathfrak a_m$. If $f\in A[X]$ and if $V_{A/\mathfrak a_i}(f)\neq\emptyset$ for every $i=1,...,m$, then show that $V_{A/\mathfrak a}(f) \neq \emptyset$. (Set $V_A(f)$ means the solutions set of $f=0$ in $A$.)

So, for all $i=1,..., m$, $V_{A/\mathfrak a_i}(f)\neq \emptyset$ means that there exists an element  $x_i$ in $A/\mathfrak a_i$ such that $f(x_i) =0$. Now, I have to construct an element $y$ in  $A/\mathfrak a$ such that $f(y)=0$.

$\mathfrak a_1\cdots\mathfrak a_n =\mathfrak a_i$ for any $i =1,...,m$ as $\mathfrak a_i$'s are ideals. So, $x_1$ is such an element.

Is my proof fine?

Comment: Hint: use the ring-theoretic version CRT - just like in the classical case in $\Bbb Z$ in the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242)

Comment: I have no idea how you arrived at the conclusion that  $a_1...a_n =a_i$, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @user26857 As all of $a_1,...,a_m$ are ideals so , using definition of ideals $aa_i \in a_i$ for all $a\in A$ and using it on $a_1 ...a_m$ along with commutativity I get $a_1 ... a_n =a_i$ for all i . Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Actually you get $a_1\cdots a_m\subseteq a_i$ for all $i$. For instance, in $\mathbb Z$ we have $(2)(3)\subsetneq(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that there is $x_i\in A$ such that $f(x_i)\in\mathfrak a_i$. By CRT there is $x\in A$ such that $x-x_i\in\mathfrak a_i$ for all $i$. Write $x=x_i+a_i$ with $a_i\in\mathfrak a_i$. Now notice that $f(x)=f(x_i)+a_ir_i$ with $r_i\in A$, and therefore $f(x)\in\mathfrak a_i$ for all $i$. Since $\bigcap\mathfrak a_i=\prod\mathfrak a_i$ we are done.

Comment: How did you deduced that  there is $x_i \in A$ such that $f(x_i) \in a_i$  . You must have used  $f(x)\in A[x]$ and $V_{A/a_i}(f)\neq \phi$ but I think that means that there exists an element $a /a_i$ in $A/a_i$ such that $f(a/a_i)=0$. Kindly explain how you wrote the 1st line of your answer.

Comment: $f(a/a_i)=0$ where? Answer: in $A/a_i$. This means that $f(a)\in a_i$, right?

Comment: Btw, $f(a/a_i)=f(a)/a_i$.

Comment: How does CRT implies exiestence of $x\in A$ in line 1 ? Do you mind showing the step? I am not able to understand how you used CRT here.

Comment: CRT says the following: the system of congruences $x\equiv x_i\bmod\mathfrak a_i$, $i=1,\dots,m$, has a solution.

Comment: How did you deduced that $\cap a_i =\prod a_i$?

Comment: This is a well known property of comaximal ideals.

Comment: Link to a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356916.